# Make protected?

Tags: discussion, status-completed

Can [this Q&A](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/42360/95-integra-ls-starter-procedure-to-replace-plunger-and-starter) be protected? Seems like a pretty useful one to me and I know I'll have use for this at some point in the future...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Done and good suggestion. (lalalalalala adding so I'm over 30 characters lalalalala)

Comment: Thanks. :) lol (also adding)

Comment: Try doing `<p></p><p></p>` to inflate the character count. (see [here](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6054/25966) for an example)